# How to convert date to (iso8601) in Mule 3.2?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, iso8601, mule-el

I need to convert this date format in **Mule 3.2**
**YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (iso8601)**
for example 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00

I use #[function:datestamp:YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD] but
this does not work

Comment: #[function:datestamp:yyyy-MM-dd]T#[function:datestamp:hh:mm:ss.SXXX]

Comment: Post this as an answer and accept it so this question doesn't show as "still open".

Answer (score 0):

The answer in real is this (my previous answer was wrong):

`<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <http:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS"/>
    <flow name="dateFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8089" path="serverdate" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[server]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="#[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(&quot;yyyy-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ&quot;).format(new java.util.Date())]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>`

Comment: Could you please add a description of how this code fixes the problem in the question?

Comment: If it works for you, please mark the answer as useful